# Sorting treeTable (primeFaces) is not working

Tags: sorting, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, treetable

I found information that primefacess now supports treeTable sorting.
http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=3017

''Usage is same as datatable via sortBy attribute of columns''

But when I add sortBy attribute sort functionality doesn't display.

There's my treeTable in **welcome.xhtml**.

```
<h:form id="form">
        <p:treeTable id="treeTable"
                     value="#{treeCheckBox.root}" var="manager"
                     selection="#{treeCheckBox.selectedNodes}" selectionMode="checkbox">

            <p:column style="width:100px" sortBy="id">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    ID
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{manager.id}"/>
            </p:column>

            <p:column style="width:100px" sortBy="description">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    Description
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{manager.description}"/>
            </p:column>

            <p:column style="width:100px" sortBy="knowledgeDate">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    KnowladgeDate
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{manager.knowledgeDate}"/>
            </p:column>
        </p:treeTable>
    </h:form>
```

And simple manager POJO.

```
    public class Manager implements Serializable{

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -1927658103477398301L;

        private String id;
        private String description;
        private String knowledgeDate;

        public Manager() {
        }

        public Manager(String id, String description, String knowledgeDate) {
            this.id = id;
            this.description = description;
            this.knowledgeDate = knowledgeDate;
        }}
//... getters and setters
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primefaces declares that they have sorting aproach for tree tale in 5 version. 
That was already released in may 2014.

But still We can't filter treeTable. Hope it would be the next feature in the next releases.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it this functions is either only available for Primefaces 5 and/or Primefaces Elite. Since I don't see anything wrong with your code I assume that you use a free version of Primefaces 4.

Comment: You right I am using primefaces 4. BTW, how can I get this elit version or 5 seems that it's not for free?

Comment: That's correct, Elite can cost a whopping [250$ per developer](http://primefaces.org/support.html#elite). I assume that the sorting function will be implemented in Primefaces 5, which will be released in [spring 2014](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=2976). Guess it's safe to say that this function will not immediately find its way into the free version of Primefaces though.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you must change this :

```
false =  " sortBy="id">"
true = " sortBy="manager.id">"
```